# Tomcat startup Failing in "opencms" version 10.5.4 web application

Tags: java, tomcat7, opencms

```
Starting OpenCms, version 10.5.4 in web application "opencms"

    Copyright (c) 2016 Alkacon Software GmbH & Co. KG
    OpenCms comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
    This is free software, and you are welcome to
    redistribute it under certain conditions.
    Please see the GNU Lesser General Public Licence for
    further details.
 ERROR org.apache.commons.digester.Digester Begin event threw exception
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.abc.opencms.repository.WebdavCmsRepository
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
        at org.apache.commons.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:210)
        at org.apache.commons.digester.Rule.begin(Rule.java:177)
        at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1583)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1892)
        at org.opencms.configuration.CmsConfigurationManager.loadXmlConfiguration(CmsConfigurationManager.java:657)
        at org.opencms.configuration.CmsConfigurationManager.loadXmlConfiguration(CmsConfigurationManager.java:379)
        at org.opencms.main.OpenCmsCore.initConfiguration(OpenCmsCore.java:1189)
        at org.opencms.main.OpenCmsCore.initContext(OpenCmsCore.java:1541)
        at org.opencms.main.OpenCmsCore.upgradeRunlevel(OpenCmsCore.java:2097)
        at org.opencms.main.OpenCmsListener.contextInitialized(OpenCmsListener.java:85)
    --------------------
    The following critical error occurred:
    Critical error during OpenCms initialization: Unable to read the OpenCms XML configuration.
    Giving up, unable to start OpenCms.
    --------------------
    ERROR org.opencms.main.OpenCmsCore Critical error during OpenCms initialization: Unable to read the OpenCms XML configuration.
    org.opencms.main.CmsException: Critical error during OpenCms initialization: Unable to read the OpenCms XML configuration.
        at org.opencms.main.OpenCmsCore.setErrorCondition(OpenCmsCore.java:370)
        at org.opencms.main.CmsInitException.setErrorCondition(CmsInitException.java:113)
        at org.opencms.main.CmsInitException.<init>(CmsInitException.java:84)
        at org.opencms.main.OpenCmsCore.initConfiguration(OpenCmsCore.java:1191)
        at org.opencms.main.OpenCmsCore.initContext(OpenCmsCore.java:1541)
        at org.opencms.main.OpenCmsCore.upgradeRunlevel(OpenCmsCore.java:2097)
        at org.opencms.main.OpenCmsListener.contextInitialized(OpenCmsListener.java:85)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5110)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5633)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1694)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1684)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    ERROR org.opencms.main.OpenCmsListener Critical error during OpenCms initialization: Unable to read the OpenCms XML configuration.
    org.opencms.main.CmsInitException: Critical error during OpenCms initialization: Unable to read the OpenCms XML configuration.
        at org.opencms.main.OpenCmsCore.initConfiguration(OpenCmsCore.java:1191)
        at org.opencms.main.OpenCmsCore.initContext(OpenCmsCore.java:1541)
        at org.opencms.main.OpenCmsCore.upgradeRunlevel(OpenCmsCore.java:2097)
        at org.opencms.main.OpenCmsListener.contextInitialized(OpenCmsListener.java:85)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5110)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5633)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1694)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1684)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 148; columnNumber: 90; Error at line 148 char 90: com.abc.opencms.repository.WebdavCmsRepository
```

Please help with this?

Comment: Looks like a problem in the XML configuration file ("Unable to read the OpenCms XML configuration") in lineNumber: 148; columnNumber: 90; Error at line 148 char 90: com.abc.opencms.repository.WebdavCmsRepository. A missing quotation mark? Wrong encoding in XML config file?

Comment: This is inside cms jar file.

Comment: I guess, @HeikoJakubzik is right. Check `opencms-importexport.xml` in folder `../webapps/WEB-INF/config/` for syntax errors.

Comment: Yes; Resolved after all configuration reset.. It was a configuration issue..Thanks @ Heiko Jakubzik @Kai